# How to Use Exploratory Data Analysis To Criticize Pre-Existing Hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, exploratory-data-analysis

Obviously, exploratory data analysis is a useful tool that can be used to support the hypothesis generation process in the social sciences. Especially in the age of big data. But, my coursework never mentions how often exploratory data analysis is used as a tool to criticize pre-existing hypotheses generated by others on the basis of their intuitions. Are there any practical resources on how to use exploratory data analysis to critique the hypotheses of others?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here. If "criticism" of a pre-existing hypothesis is equated with formal testing, it's *confirmatory* analysis you're then performing. EDA can play a role in suggesting specific alternative hypotheses for such formal testing (vs the pre-existing hypothesis as the null).